# If $\tan \theta = 3\frac{15}{16}$, then find $\sin \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan \theta = 3\cfrac{15}{16}$, then find $\sin \theta$.

Comment: hint: $\tan^2x=\frac{\sin^2x}{1-\sin ^2 x}$.

Comment: a decimal number! What a nightmare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us rewrite $3 \frac{15}{16}$ as an improper fraction. So we get $3 \dfrac{15}{16} = \dfrac{16\cdot3+15}{16} = \dfrac{63}{16}$

We know that $\tan(\theta) = \dfrac{o}{a}$, where $o$ and $a$ are the opposite and adjacent sides of $\theta$. We also know through the Pythagorean theorem that the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{o^2+a^2} = \sqrt{63^2+16^2} = 65$. Recall that:
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{o}{h}$$ where $h$ is the hypotenuse and $o$ is the opposite side. Subbing in the values we obtained and get:
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{63}{65}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\tan\theta=\frac{opp}{adj}$. Thus you have a right triangle with side lengths $\text{adj}=16$ and $\text{opp}=63$. I think you can solve it from here.